# Why Is My ASP.NET MVC Model Filled in the Controller, but Null in the View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have really dumb issue that's going on.

I have an ASP.NET MVC page that absolutely refuses to display my viewmodel. Even if I remove the database results that are assigned to the viewmodel and just hardcode the value I want in the viewmodel property inside of the controller, it still doesn't work. During debugging, I can see that the proper data is placed inside of the ViewModel from within the controller, but the View acts like it never gets it. Using the quickwatch, I can see that the data is inside of the field.

It will display the names of the variable it's using in the LabelFors, but it will NEVER display the variable's value in the text box.

View

```
@model Project1.ViewModels.OrderNoLocationViewModel

@{ Html.EnableClientValidation(); }
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()    
    <table class="item-display" style="width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td class="label">
                <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Shipper):</div>
            </td>
            <td class="value">
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Shipper)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Shipper)
                </div>
            </td>
    </table>
}
```

Controller

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]
        public ActionResult Index(OrderNoLocationViewModel model, string consigneeFilter, string orderNoFilter, string button)
{
  model = new OrderNoLocationViewModel()
                {
                    Shipper = "Ray"
                };

                return View(model);
}
```

I have no earthly idea what is going on... I have other pages that work, and this is literally the only page that is acting like this.

Please help! :(

EDIT:

Routes

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
        }
```

Comment: you are passing a new instance of OrderNoLocationViewModel() which only has the Carrier property set. Since you haven't provided the code for this viewmodel class, we can't tell if the Shipper property ever gets set here.

Comment: Do you intentionally have different variable names for some reason? Carrier in the Controller, Shipper in the View.

Comment: You are setting "carrier" in the controller, but "shipper" is the form field in the view, so with your current code I wouldn't expect to see anything.

Comment: Oops, that was a typo on my part. I'll update the question.

Comment: What happens when you change HttpPost to HttpGet ?

Comment: It returns the Ray correctly with the HttpGet version, but I do Posts so my users can get data... I don't have any other constructors set for the OrderNoLocationViewModel, so none of the variables are being set.

Comment: it looks like your routes may be set up incorrectly.  Can you show us your routes?

Comment: Routes like in the global.asax? It's nothing special, but I'll edit the question with them.

Comment: ...how are you even posting this? There's no button... If this isn't your exact code we can't really be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not entirely clear what you are trying to do here or why you are doing it this way. If you want to display a form to edit the properties of `OrderNoLocationViewModel` then initially display it with a GET method

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var model = model = new OrderNoLocationViewModel();
  model.Shipper = "Ray";
  return View(model);
}
```

The textbox will now display "Ray".

When you post back to

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(OrderNoLocationViewModel model)
{
}
```

`model.Shipper` will contain the value of whatever is in the textbox (which will be *"Ray"* if the user has not altered the value).

Reassigning the model as you have done here in the POST method

```
model = new OrderNoLocationViewModel()
{
  Shipper = "Ray"
};
return View(model);
```

has no affect unless you clear `ModelState` (the view takes the values from `ModelState`). I assume that in your case the initial value of `Shipper` is `null` or `string.Empty` so when the view is returned, its still `null` or `string.Empty` To see this work, amend the POST method to

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(OrderNoLocationViewModel model)
{
  ModelState.Clear();
  model.Shipper = "Some other value";
  return View(model);
}
```

The text box will now contain *"Some other value"*.
However this is not something you really want to do since clearing `ModelState` also removes all validation errors as well